# Headphones impedance for bass guitar combo/DI box

Tags: amplifiers, electric-bass-guitar, electronics, headphones

I used to practice my bass through my pair of old - trusty - worn Grado SR80 headphones which sound amazing, but they are 8 years old already and seem to have a blown dynamic (buzzing on low frequencies in the right ear). I'm thinking about getting something like Beyerdynamic DT-990 Pro to replace them for same purposes (mainly music listening and some late hours practice). Grados are 32 Ohms, but I am considering full-blown 250 Ohm Beyers version, because I have a proper headphone amp for my PC. The question is, whether high impedance headphones will be ok to use with my Laney RB2 combo headphone out or any generic DI/Preamp box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I did 2 things

1. I wrote to Laney and asked them, if it'll be ok to use higher impedance headphones with their combo, and the answer was:

> Yes it will be fine because the headphone out has a limiter!

2. I bought the pair, plug into the combo out and it sounds pretty good! Way better than my old Grados.

So I guess we can conclude - 250 Ohm headphones should be fine with your electronics, but ask the manufacturer first.